# why does my if statement not let me put = sign

Tags: python

My if statement not working

Under the if statement, python will not let me put a `=` sign.
I tried a < and > and those worked fine.

```
score = 0

if score = 4:
    difficulty = 50
else:
    print('hi')
```

Comment: Might be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 = ;) like this

```
score = 0
if score == 4: 
    difficulty = 50 
else: 
    print('hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two equal ==

```
if score == 4:
    difficulty = 50
else:
    print('hi')
```